# changing a variable based on dropdowns that also doesn't refresh page

Tags: forms, post, submit

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have a simple form that has dropdowns with priced items in them. When a user changes a dropdown option it will change the "base price" of the overall product.

^^ That is all working ^^

The kicker is that I was this all to work without refreshing the page because right now I'm using the this.form.submit() on the < select >. Reason being, if a user is at the bottom part of the page and they select another option it will take them back to the top of the page when I just want to keep them going on selecting more options.

I've tried the ajax methods of not refreshing page, and got it to work but then my "post" variables don't work. Thus I can't keep a running total of the base price.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am understanding this is you need to submit without refresh, please see this tutorial:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Comment: Well, it's not a "submit" technically it just when they change the dropdown.

Comment: 2 things need to happen, update the price AND do not refresh the page.

Comment: Look at the section: Process our Form Submission with jQuery’s AJAX Function. You can use Jquery's ajax function to update the price without refreshing the page.

Comment: Somehow I just can't figure it out, I've looked at that tutorial for 2 days straight. Thanks though